# Retain the placeholders on the file, with the previous dragged placeholder's coordinate | JS code

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, typescript, placeholder

I was working on this problem
Go to this link to get HTML, CSS, JS code :
https://codepen.io/ValerioEmanuele/pen/pGRZqe?editors=0010

Here's the HTML, CSS, JS Code for draging and droping placeholder
It's basic code to drag and drop placeholders on a pdf file.

I want an addition to the code written there, it opens like this:
[image: File opens like this]

What, I want is that **RAPINA** named placeholder retained in *contestant name*  and **CASUAL_G00** named placeholder in *contact name* .

I need help for how can I hardcode the location of X and Y axis (given that when we drag and drop RAVINA to Contestant name and CASUAL_G00 to Contact Name, and click the button to check the coordinates,

check from -

```
"SHOW PDF PLACEHOLDERS COORDINATES"
```

[image]

We will get these coordinates for RAVINA AND CASUAL_G00

[image]

Basically what I want is, a code what should I write in js file so that when I hardcode the X and Y coordinates for the placeholders
and reload the pdf file/ or page then the placeholders should remain retained at their previous location where ( we have hardcoded the coordinates.)

If anyone can figure out the js code to hardcode these coordinates on that pdf file ?